# How to spin up one dataflow from other dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Have a requirement to Spin up a Dataflow job from another dataflow. First Dataflow will be listening to a topic and based on the message it receive, it has to spin up the second Dataflow.
Trying to implement it in Java.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();          
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/dataflow-begining/templates:launch");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gcsPath", "gs template location")); request.setEntity(entity); HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I am getting an Authorization issue while the first dataflow try to spin up the second dataflow.
can some one guide me on how can i pass the google credential during the HttpCall. ? 
I don't want to create an AccessToken before every call, is it possible to get the access token from serviceAccount or somewhere and set the accesstoken during the http call.

Comment: I don't think this is a good pattern for chaining your dataflow jobs like this, if it is even possible. The common pattern is use a separate system to trigger new jobs based on signals of previous job. E.g Cloud Composer might be better on this task.

Comment: You need to all a role to the Cloud Dataflow controller service account to be able to create another Dataflow cluster. However, I do NOT recommend this. A mistake in your code, retries, etc could be costly. Cloud Dataflow runs on Compute Engine. You will need to access the Metadata server to get an Access Token. This is then used in the HTTP `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>` header. If this does not make sense to you, stop and don't try this from a cluster.

Comment: Agree with @RuiWang. It's not the right pattern. It's better to trigger a function or something else, and this external element of the dataflow will start the new one. In addition, Dataflow worker use Default compute instance service account. To prevent to allow too much role to it, it's better to have a seperate processing element for doing this.